# How to insert, replace and delete regions of a file, in Java?

Tags: java, file, static-code-analysis

I'm looking for an implemented class (in Java) which handles insertion, replacement and deletion of text for an existing file, just like [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) does.

The reason I do not want to use a StringBuilder is that I want to avoid having all the file content in memory.

The purpose is to apply patches to a file which contains code in any programming language.

Comment: What kind of file?  Many of them have formats that might not handle a random insertion.

Comment: The files to be altered contain programming code. This will be used for a static code analysis tool to patch errors on the code.

Comment: There's no class that allows you to delete or replace regions of a file in such a way that the file size changes. But have a look at [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Or just create a new file from the old file, replacing regions as necessary.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException currently I created a new file from the old file replacing regions as necessary, and finally stepping over the original file with the temporary file, it just felt strange that there is no handler for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a class should do one thing, and do it well.

That means that it is unlikely you'll find a single class that reads the code, turns it into an internal representation (parse tree), detects the issue at hand, alters the internal representation, and writes the internal representation back out to disk.

With that in mind, there are a number of projects that you might be able to extend to add in your desired functionality.

[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) parses Java code, with the intent of reporting the stylistic errors.  To do this it must read the code, turn it into an internal representation, and detect (formatting) issues.  It might be a good starting point, depending on your goals.

[PMD](https://pmd.github.io) is a static code analysis tool.  For it to find issues in Java source code, it must:  read the code, turn it into an internal representation, and detect (structural) issues.

Note that neither of these tools does everything you wish; but, they are close.  All you will have to do is construct a "fixer" that runs on the parsed tree, fixing the detected problem.  Then you will either need to find if the tool provides an "outputter" that reconstructs the text of the code from the internal parsed (tree) representation, and use it to generate the desired text which you will then save to disk.

If the tree-to-text module doesn't exist, you might have to write it.

Source code is subject to rules, and while you might feel that you don't need these extra steps, your code will have a lifetime much greater than it would have by skipping these steps.  Simply pasting in a line of code might not make sense with unexpected input.  For example, assuming you add the `@Overrides` tag to a Java method, this pseudo code will fail

```
currentLine = next();
if (currentLine.detectMethod() and isAnOverride(currentLine().getMethod())) {
    code.insertBefore(currentline, "@Overrides");
}
```

Because someone will feed your code this

```
public
void
myMethod(
  String one,
  String two,
  String three)
{
  System.out.println("Haha!  I broke you!");
}
```

possibly leading to

```
public
void
@Overrides
myMethod(
  String one,
  String two,
  String three)
{
  System.out.println("Haha!  I broke you!");
}
```

And you can say "Well, nobody should do that!" But, if the language permits it, then you'll be at odds with the language itself.

If you don't believe me, a line-by-line processor would not detect "public" as a method, nor "void" as a method, but would detect "myMethod(" as the beginning of a (misidentified) package private multi-line method.

Comment: Bravo! Is good to still read such good and educational answers.

Comment: @gtgaxiola Thank you for the kind complement.

Comment: This post is educational but I think all the OP is looking for is a class that lets you open a file named abcde.fgh, go to byte offset 12345, and replace the next 6 characters with "hello world".

Comment: I'm currently one of the developers for the auto-fixables feature for PMD. As @DodgyCodeException mentioned, one of the operations to be supported should be replacement, but also to add a string in an arbitrary position of the file without erasing the following bytes, as well as deleting bytes from the file in an arbitrary position.

Comment: @gibarsin Thanks for maintaining PMD.  I've had a lot of fun with it in the past.  I've even extended it (once) to handle PLSQL to detect some common PLSQL problems.  I'll take a second peek now that there's an auto fixer effort.

Comment: I appreciate very much the time and effort you are putting into this topic.